Does Mongoose Update methods don't work without .then chaining?
I have the below code
Product.findOneAndUpdate({ name: 'Cycling Jersey' }, { onSale: true }, { new: true })
    .then(data => {
        console.log("IT WORKED!")
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("OH NO ERROR!")
        console.log(err)
    })

It updates the databse, and prints the updated document to the terminal, however, when I have only the below line
Product.findOneAndUpdate({ name: 'Cycling Jersey' }, { onSale: true }, { new: true })

The update doesn't happens. It should happen right? The .then is just to notify me when the update has completed, but if I don't use .then it should update the database in background atleast. If I open Mongo Shell after 5 mins or more, nothing has changed in Database, why is that so?

This is a common question when you first start using mongoose. See the answers to this question. Node is single threaded so you want database queries to be done asynchronously otherwise they will block the event loop. Methods such as findOneAndUpdate need to be handled in an async way so mongoose developers give you a then() method or exec() if you really want a promise. Alternatively you can use the await keyword which is the preferred way.

This was surprisingly difficult to answer. However both the documentation and the source code show that this method doesn’t really start the operation and return a promise. Instead it configures the query object to carry out the operation, and returns the query object. However the query object itself has a “then” method, which does start the real action and return a promise.
So you are right: nothing really happens until you call then().
This may have been done to allow additional chained calls to override or adjust the query before then() is called.
Although you chose to write your then() calls by hand, is worth noting that this method is also compatible with the “await” keyword because that keyword actually works with any “thenable” (any object with a “then” method attached that behaves like it would on a promise), it doesn’t strictly require a promise.

Mongo queries are not promises. They are thenables, there is a difference. They are thenables to give the convenience of using the results after the completion of the command.
But that does not mean that the commands run as soon as you call the function.
This is from the docs:

Mongoose queries are not promises. Queries are thenables, meaning they have a .then() method for async/await as a convenience. However, unlike promises, calling a query's .then() executes the query, so calling then() multiple times will throw an error.

There are two ways to execute the query. By using the then()/await() or by using the callback function as second parameter.

Most of the time, these types of questions have been answered under the background of thenables. However this post is trying to answer this question about query object from its overall design and usage point of view. Please see if it is useful.
Product.findOneAndUpdate({ name: 'Cycling Jersey' }, { onSale: true }, { new: true }) .then(data => { console.log("IT WORKED!") console.log(data); }) .catch(err => { console.log("OH NO ERROR!") console.log(err) })

Though the statement above looks like a “single chain” all the way, it is not so. Technically speaking, the statement includes two main constructs - one method invocation and one method chaining. The reason for this break-up will be discussed now. The first part of the same statement shown below is not a method chaining but a method invocation. A method chaining will always return the same object (modified) on which the method is called. It means the method “then” does not return a query object instead it returns a promise object. If it was a method chaining “then” method should have returned the query object instead. Therefore it can be said that the first part of the same statement shown below is not a method chaining but a method invocation.
Product.findOneAndUpdate({ name: 'Cycling Jersey' }, { onSale: true }, { new: true }) .then(data => { console.log("IT WORKED!") console.log(data); })

The other part of the same statement shown below is a method chaining. However it is to take note that the underlying object over here is not the query object but the promise object returned by the “then” method. It means although it is a method chaining, it does not chain any methods in the query object.
 .catch(err => { console.log("OH NO ERROR!") console.log(err) })

The nutshell is that there is no method chaining in the given statement as far as the query object is concerned. This point is unlike the original post which assumes there is a chaining in query object.
If the above discussion makes sense, then it will be easy for us to get into the following conclusion.
As we know method chaining is software component design pattern normally applied to facilitate object configuration. For example, please see the following examples quoted from mongoose documentation. The main difference between the two statements given below is the way the query document has been mentioned. While the first statement mentions the query document by a JSON document, the second statement does the same using query builder or the query builder methods like “find”, “where”, “equals”, “gt”, “in” and etc. Not only that, the other methods “limit”, “sort”, “select” are also chaining methods. The defining characteristic of all these chaining methods is that it returns the same object in which it has invoked - that is the query object itself. It makes chaining possible.
Now once this chaining objective has been met, it means the query object has been configured fully, it is now time to use it. This is where the method exec comes in. Again please note “exec” is not a chaining method, instead it is a method invocation which returns a different object -  a promise object. It makes so much sense, since the database operation triggered is asynchronous in nature, therefore the exec method which models this operation has to return a promise object. Similar to exec, the methods “then” and “catch” also return a promise object after initiating the underlying asynchronous operation. Without any of these methods, the database operations will not be initiated. This is the way a query object has been designed and developed by its developers after studying its possible use cases. Don’t we find this component nicely does its job?. Yes it does it nicely.
// With a JSON doc
await Person.
  find({
    occupation: /host/,
    'name.last': 'Ghost',
    age: { $gt: 17, $lt: 66 },
    likes: { $in: ['vaporizing', 'talking'] }
  }).
  limit(10).
  sort({ occupation: -1 }).
  select({ name: 1, occupation: 1 }).
  exec();

// Using query builder
await Person.
  find({ occupation: /host/ }).
  where('name.last').equals('Ghost').
  where('age').gt(17).lt(66).
  where('likes').in(['vaporizing', 'talking']).
  limit(10).
  sort('-occupation').
  select('name occupation').
  exec();

Notes:

A query object is a thenable object since it implements a then method which returns a promise.

The method catch is available in both query object and promise object. However it behaves differently. The one in a query object works almost like the method then. The only difference is that it takes the rejection handler. More can be seen in mongoose documentation under the section Query.prototype.catch().


